Power Automate HTTP request to SharePoint error - No property exists in type
Hope someone can help.
I am trying to use an http request to SharePoint from power automate to get documents (properties) in a site library. I am using a filter to match day and month in a date field. It works on a field called ExpiryDate but does not work on a field called RenewalCancelDate.


I can't figure out why it's working with one custom field, but not another. Appreciate any help.

Are you sure that internal field name is the same as you are using in your call and its a same data type?

Yeah I checked this multiple times in the URL and in the JSON dump without the filter. The name RenewalCancelDate is correct. Maybe this is a bug with the API?
